# Magento : Configuration -> Advanced -> System Menu Not Displayed

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, configuration

In my magento, system does not send emails. so I would like to access email settings config menu as shown [here](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-set-the-return-path-email-in-magento.html).

However the `Advanced -> System` menu doesn't appear, under `Advanced` I can only see `Admin`, `Advanced` and `Developper`.

I can't find anything about this issue. Where should I look first?

Comment: Please check if the admin user with which you have logged in has rights to view System > Advanced > System section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've checked the `admin` role and it has access to `all` resources.

Comment: Check in `app\code\core\Mage\Core\etc\system.xml` file for `<system translate="label" module="core">` Also check if it is rewritten in local code pool.